# How To Slide in div with full width

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I want to slide in a div on a mobile device with a couple of boxes without the box element being sliced off during the slide-in animation, how can I achieve this with CSS? I have the below code and Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dealwap/prwdm724/. The issue happens only on mobile devices.

HTML:

```css
    .box {
      flex: 0 0 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .container{
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      scrollbar-width: none;
      animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    }


    @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to this last box on the far right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhywa.png

Comment: Yes, the last boxes on the right, I need to prevent it from being sliced off during slide in while maintaining the overflow: auto so the user can slide to see more boxes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pragmatically: 1.) `flex-wrap:nowrap;` 2.) `transform: translateX(-200%);`

```css
    .box {
      flex: 0 0 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .container{
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap:nowrap;
      margin: auto;      
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    }

    @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.container{
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
}
```

If i understood your question right this fix the problem.

```css
    .box {
      flex: 0 0 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .container{
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    }


    @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need the overflow to be there so the user can slide to see more boxes. This `wrap` will prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to provide `width` to `.box` elements. Providing `flex-basis` alone is not enough.

**CSS only:**

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 130, 130);
  margin: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: purple;
  width: fit-content;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft normal forwards;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  99.99% {
    width: fit-content;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='slideMe' class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

---

**Using JavaScript:**
Using Animations API this is easy to achieve.

```js
const slideIn = new KeyframeEffect(slideMe, 
                             { transform: 'translateX(0%)' }, 
                             { fill: 'forwards', duration: 4000 });

const anim = new Animation(slideIn);
anim.onfinish = e => slideMe.style.width = '100%';

btn.onclick = (e) => {
  anim.play();
  e.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```css
.box {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 130, 130);
  margin: 10px;
  left: 10px;

  width: 80px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: purple;
  width: fit-content;

  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Show</button>
<div id='slideMe' class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, I want an approach that doesn't require JS, KeyframeEffect is not supported by every browsers.

Comment: @dealwap you had `javascript` tag on your question... I've added CSS only solution to the answer.

Comment: great workournd   
"99.99% {
    width: fit-content;
}" it is an out of the box thought on css

Answer (score 0):

you need to calculate full width of `.container` and then change `translateX` , to goes left as much as it's width to hide from viewport. and with add `animation` to silde it right.
now for calculate  the full width , you can use `calce()` function.
i set widths of `.box`s in a variable (`--box-width`). and set in calc function

> calc( (box-width + side margins) * (- box number) ) 
> add a `minus` sign for goes to left

`calc( (var(--box-width) + 20px) * -10)`

```css
body{
   --box-width: 80px;
}
.container {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1  slideInFromLeft;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 var(--box-width);
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
  transform: translatex(calc( (var(--box-width) + 20px) * -10));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
   </div>
```

and that work better without knowing the number of `box` element,  with a little pure js .

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  childNumber = container.childElementCount
  container.style.setProperty('--childNumber', childNumber)
  container.classList.add('animated')
})
```

```css
body{
   --box-width: 80px;
}
.container { 
  --childNumber : 0;
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 10; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}
.container.animated{
 visibility: visible;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1  slideInFromLeft;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 var(--box-width);
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
} 
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
  transform: translatex(calc( (var(--box-width) + 20px) * var(--childNumber) * -1));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this didn't solve the problem. I need an approach that doesn't require me to know the number of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .box {
      flex: 0 0 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .container{
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    }


    @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

If you dont want it sliced off then margin is NOT needed but if you really want it there then just set it to auto

```css
    .box {
      flex: 0 0 80px;
      height: 80px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: red;
      left: 10px;
    }

    .container{
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    }


    @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

but to be honest with you I dont really know what you need if you just dont want it going offscreen just add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to container